# Restfull JSON Webservice: The best way to go?

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest, zend-framework

I want to write a webservice for my android apps. It needs to be a **restful JSON webservice**. I am searching for the **best way to do it**. It needs to be **fast**, and not to hard to use or learn if necessary.

*The options I have right now are:*

- Write my own PHP restfull webservice. [Example](http://www.angularcode.com/demo-of-a-simple-crud-restful-php-service-used-with-angularjs-and-mysql/)
- Use the [SLIM Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) for routing my requests. [Example](http://codoki.com/2015/01/27/getting-started-with-slim-framework/)
- Use [Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/) as base. But I find Zend slow?
- Use ASP.NET for creating the webservice. But the hosting is expensive?
- Java webservice, never used before.

So what is the best option to go for? *I cannot choose which way to go?* Or is there another, maybe better option that I forgot?

Comment: SLIM is the only real modern REST framework that exists for PHP (to my best knowledge), it can be used with express and angular for example. But there must be some native solutions for android working out of the box? Besides that the question is OT, "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam_ .... [**read more**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"

Comment: You can also check apigility. It's a framework built on Zend by Zend Technologies to build api fast

Comment: Slim is great if you want to use php for your webservice. Another popular micro-framework for php is  [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/). They both are very similar to express (node.js) and flask (python) and so on. However, have you looked into a 'backend as a service' like  [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), highly recommended!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked at al your proposals and I am going for the slim framework. But thx for all the options.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Jello Framework](http://jello-framework.com) (I am the author). It is an end-to-end Java framework including comprehensive Data Authorization model, a powerful RESTful engine optimized for Google App Engine.